# Check if file exists in folder or not (SSIS and SQL Server 2014/2016)

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssis, sql-server-2014

I have a table column where clients will insert the full path of file with filename.

For example: in table `FileInfo` I have a column `FilePath` with a sample value of

```
C:\Users\MyComp\Documents\Program\SSIS\Archived Email\rq123456.msg
```

I need to build a SSIS package to check whether this file path in the `FilePath` column is correct and the file exists or not. If yes, then proceed ahead, and if no, then send email to client.

I am new to SSIS, Could you please help me how can I complete this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a script task and set a variable using:

```
System.IO.File.Exists([filepath]);
```

Or you can use a foreach (file) and set the mask as the complete path. I tend to use this approach solely so I can hand the package off to someone that isn't scared of c#.

Either way you need to get the filepath from the table which you can do via execute SQL task in to a variable.

Here is the control flow to do your work:

[image]

Notice the function on the path leading to the send mail. It is set to counter==0